# How to read the File present in Azure Data Lake Store through azure power shell commands?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-lake

Is there any way to read the file data present in Azure data lake store with azure powershell cmdlets?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the step by step on just the powershell itself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-powershell

You can use Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent thereafter

Answer (score 1):

Try [Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.datalakestore/v1.0.12/get-azurermdatalakestoreitemcontent) which gets the contents of a file in Azure Data Lake Store.  An example:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent -AccountName "yourADLSAccountName" -Path "/input/someFile.txt"
```